# Windows 11 wakes on lid open

Tags: windows, windows-11

Computer wakes after shutdown on lid open. Incredibly annoying. When I ask the computer to shutdown I want an actual shutdown. Power button should be the only item that can wake.

I have enabled the open lid option in the power settings following other questions and set it to do nothing.
[image: see bologna]

I'm shutting down with cmd> shutdown -s -t 0 not just sleeping.

Please. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned the make of your laptop.

For e.g. for Dell laptop the steps are mentioned here,
https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-in/000124946/how-to-enable-or-disable-the-power-on-lid-open-feature-on-your-newer-notebook

In short you need to go into your BIOS and not OS to change these settings.

In the BIOS you will need to go into Power or Power Management setting. There will be "Power on lid open" setting in the BIOS. You will need to toggle it to avoid starting your laptop on lid open.